# Server was renamed without running Rename-SPServer. Now what?

Tags: 2013, administration

SharePoint 2013. SharePoint and SQL are installed on the same box. Service Pack 1 was installed. At this point, prior to running the config wizard, someone decided that it was a good time to rename the server. So the server was renamed without running rename-spserver or doing anything else along those lines. Once the server was renamed, the config wizard was run. At this point, SharePoint wasn't running so well, so the server was renamed again back to the original name.

SharePoint is actually mostly functioning, but a few service apps are throwing errors such as the User Profile Service.

Is there anything else to try besides reinstalling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, it is highly recommended to rebuild the farm (as it is single Server). But if you dont want to re install SharePoint, here's a couple of things to try:

- Remove the Distributed Cache instance `Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`
- If you have User Profile sync services configured, stop that one.
- Then do `Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance`
- Start the User Profile sync.
- You might need to re run the config wizard (psconfig).

Comment: I'm curious if that worked for you with the dist. cache (if you tried).  I don't think you can remove the last server from the farm.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try and just re-provision the problem services.  The big one is the distributed cache service.  If that is hosed up - it can cause issues across your farm, and you will end up fighting the AppFabric stuff to correct it.  At that point with a single server - I think it will be faster to rebuild and just attach your content databases.